# How to resolve Webform Warning 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach'?

Tags: webforms

I'm getting this warning after upgrading the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module to version 7.x-4.9: (I'm using Drupal 7.38)

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   _webform_select_options_to_text() (line 1034 of /home/user/www/tryouts/survey_test/sites/all/modules/contrib/webform/components/select.inc).

Here are some code samples related to the warning.

```
$extra['options'] = _webform_select_options_to_text(array(t('poor'), t('average'), t('good'), t('excellent')));
$extra['questions'] = _webform_select_options_to_text(array(t('question one'), t('question two'), t('question three')));

$component['extra']['options_source'] = $source_name;
if ($source_name && isset($info[$source_name])) {
$options = _webform_select_options_to_text(_webform_select_options($component, FALSE, FALSE));
}
else {
  $options = '';
}

/**
 * Convert an array of options into text.
 */
function _webform_select_options_to_text($options) {
  $output = '';
  $previous_key = FALSE;

  foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
```

Any suggestions about what I can do to fix this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report for the Webform module. Please report all bugs to the issue queues on Drupal.org as we can't deal with them here. Many thanks